# Unsure about what kind of data type to use here

Tags: c, pointers

There is a function that I have to use that looks like this:

```
void pushNode (struct onode** head, struct onode* node) ;
```

I tried to use this:

```
struct onode *head = NULL;
head=malloc(sizeof(struct onode));

struct onode *tempO;

pushNode(*head,tempO);
```

To which I receive this error in the terminal:

```
expected ‘struct onode **’ but argument is of type ‘struct onode’
```

I am not sure what to put instead of `*head`.
Any light you could shed on this would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use:

```
pushNode(*head, tempO);
```

It *dereferences* `head`, turning the `struct onode *` into a `struct onode`.
You want to *take its address*, which could be said to be the opposite of dereferencing:

```
pushNode(&head, tempO);
```

Taking its address will make it from a `struct onode *` into a `struct onode **`.

Comment: Thank you! Pointers in practice are very confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting instead `pushNode(&head,tempO);`

The address of the pointer that is a pointer to a pointer, that is `struct node **`.